# How do I add OnChange event to select element that is styled with custom-form-elements.js?

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange, dom-events, custom-formatting

This works just fine to call an OnChange event:

```
<FORM>
<SELECT ONCHANGE="alert(this.name + ' changed: ' + this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE="1">Option 1</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="2">Option 2</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="3">Option 3</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</FORM>
```

But when I use this styling package:

https://web.archive.org/web/20161013011416/http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

The OnChange event no longer works.

```
<FORM>
<SELECT class="styled" ONCHANGE="alert(this.name + ' changed: ' + this.value)">
<OPTION VALUE="1">Option 1</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="2">Option 2</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="3">Option 3</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</FORM>
```

Anyway to make the OnChange event with the custom-form-elements.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on the page you linked to ;)

Scroll to the bottom and you will read:

> **onChange and other JavaScript events**
>
> This script utilizes JavaScript's onChange and other events. Because
>   these events can only be used once, if you want to add more functions
>   to an event, you will need to call them from inside my script.

::EDIT::

The `Custom.clear` and `Custom.choose` functions are both functions that will be called in the `onChange` event. So my guess is you modify the js-file as follows, and see what comes out:

```
clear: function() {
    // add your code here. example:
    alert(this.name + ' changed: ' + this.value);

    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var b = 0; b < inputs.length; b++) {
        if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + checkboxHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "checkbox" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].checked == true && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 -" + radioHeight*2 + "px";
        } else if(inputs[b].type == "radio" && inputs[b].className == "styled") {
            inputs[b].previousSibling.style.backgroundPosition = "0 0";
        }
    }
},
choose: function() {
    // add your code here. example:
    alert(this.name + ' changed: ' + this.value);

    option = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for(d = 0; d < option.length; d++) {
        if(option[d].selected == true) {
            document.getElementById("select" + this.name).childNodes[0].nodeValue = option[d].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: instead of writing chunks of code in the js-file, you should just call you own custom function once from the `clear` and/or `choose` function(s).

Comment: Good catch!  Where and how would I call the OnChange function within the script? Thanks!

Comment: Note (for other readers): Using just the choose function code addition is sufficient for a select statement that already has something pre-selected.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem....It may not be the most elegant way to fix this but I putted the radio button inside a span tag and called the onclick event from there. This thing drome me crazy for days... Hope this helps